# How can I get the real ip address of a client when using Traefik on k3s?

Tags: traefik, traefik-ingress, k3s

I have gone through many blog posts and SO questions as well as k3s documentation and am still coming up short getting the real ip address of clients rather than the internal cluster ip address.

I have a standard k3s install using Traefik 1.8. As indicated in several github issues, I have set all my services to use Clusterip and I set externalTrafficPolicy: Local for my Traefik and apache services per this: https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/issues/1652

The strange thing is, it seems that Traefik is passing along any headers like x-forwarded-for because if I manually add an x-forwarded-for with my ip address into my browser request, the result in the apache logs has my ip as well as the internal cluster ip separated by commas.

Is there something that gets hit before the Traefik instance when traffic comes in to the cluster that should be injecting the ip address?

Answer (score 3):

It appears there are many things that can cause this problem. In my case, it was one of the more common issues. I simply had to patch the k3s traefik manifest to have hostNetwork: true.

```
kubectl patch deployment traefik --patch '{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"hostNetwork":true}}}}'
```

It should be noted that it is not recommended to manually modify this manifest as it is managed by helm. So if the helm process runs again or k3s is reinstalled or updated, it will revert and you will have to run this patch again. You would have to modify the k3s helm chart for traefik or implement your own in place of the k3s one to get this change to stick.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an extensive discussion on this topic in the k3s Discussions here: https://github.com/k3s-io/k3s/discussions/2997 .

However, for me, none of the provided answers works, but YMMV.